# How can I use an object's fields as the domain for an ordinal scale in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to recreate Mike Bostock's [pie chart small multiples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111). Bostock makes a single SVG for each pie chart, and uses an array of integers as the dataset:

```
var data = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];
```

For my part, I'd like to use `d3.csv` to load an array of objects in and use those as my data. The CSV looks like this:

```
count_1,count_2
4.39,1.64
0.4894,0.0413
32.661,11.343
```

Clearly, I'm screwing up something pretty basic, but I'm a noob, and can't figure out what. Here's my script (I've left in the comments by Mike Bostock on his original script):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

// Define the data as a two-dimensional array of numbers. If you had other
// data to associate with each number, replace each number with an object, e.g.,
// `{key: "value"}`.

d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var dataset1 = data

console.log(dataset1)



var test_dataset = [
[4.39,1.64],
[0.4894,0.0413],
[32.661,11.343],
[24.61,100.0875],
[1.969142857,0.505642857],
[6.186428571,3.160357143],
[0.604761905,3.774738095],
[6.0212,2.4136],
[1.2275,0.2935],
[1.1012,1.0771],
[5.605666667,19.395],
];

console.log(test_dataset)



// Define the margin, radius, and color scale. The color scale will be
// assigned by index, but if you define your data using objects, you could pass
// in a named field from the data object instead, such as `d.name`. Colors
// are assigned lazily, so if you want deterministic behavior, define a domain
// for the color scale.
var m = 10,
    r = 100,
    z = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain([d.right, d.wrong])
                    .range(["e7969c","9ecae1"])

// Insert an svg element (with margin) for each row in our dataset. A child g
// element translates the origin to the pie center.
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", (r + m) * 2)
    .attr("height", (r + m) * 2)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + m) + "," + (r + m) + ")");//translate from corner of svg

// The data for each svg element is a row of numbers (an array). We pass that to
// d3.layout.pie to compute the angles for each arc. These start and end angles
// are passed to d3.svg.arc to draw arcs! Note that the arc radius is specified
// on the arc, not the layout.
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(d3.layout.pie())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r / 2)
        .outerRadius(r))
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

});


function type(d) {
  d.right = +d.count_1;
  d.wrong= +d.count_2;
  return d;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I first interpreted Mike's comments about setting up `z`, the scale, thus:

```
 z = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain([d.right, d.wrong])
                    .range(["e7969c","9ecae1"])
```

but that leads to the following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined**

`(anonymous function) @ (index):55
(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:1
t @ d3.v3.min.js:1
u @ d3.v3.min.js:1`

I then tried to set up the scale in another way:

```
z = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain([function(d) { return d.right;}, function(d) { return d.wrong;}])
                .range(["e7969c","9ecae1"])
```

But this leads to another error: **TypeError: a.map is not a function**

I've set up a [block with an example of what's going on](http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/5a51e5ac4ee2cf024e34). I'm pretty sure there's something really basic that I'm not grasping, so would appreciate anyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to pass in the result of your `type` function as your domain (d.right, d.wrong), you you're never actually calling `type`.

Figure out what data you want to pass into `type`, call `type` with that, and use the result in your domain like `.domain([d.right, d.wrong])`

Comment: Oh I see, type is passed as a callback to `.csv` and applied to each entry? That would mean `data` as passed to the callback of `.csv` would be an array of objects `{right, wrong}`. You just need to do your logic on each of those objects in the array.

Comment: Yes, type is applied to each item in d3.csv, but the array of objects is `{count_1, count_2, right, wrong}`. Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "need to do your logic on each of those objects in the array"?

Comment: `d` isn't defined where you're trying to use it in `.domain`. Reading the comment left by Mike Bostock, it looks like you want that domain to be the max/min of the dataset, so you'll need to calculate that and assign it to `d` before making the `.domain` call.

Comment: My "logic on each object" comment assumed you were trying to set the domain to each value of `right`, `wrong` in the array, but per above comment I think I was incorrect.

Comment: I don't think that this requires a max/min calculation, since this is an ordinal scale — each values is associated with a particular color. That would be spot on if this were a case of, say, linear scales. Here, however, there are only 2 values, so there's no need to look for a min/max.

Comment: I'm not super clear on your end goal and I keep guessing wrong, but the root problem is that you're trying to get values off `d` but `d` isn't defined.

Comment: My end goal is to load object values which I've loaded using `d3.csv` as the domain in the `d3.scale.ordinal()` function. I know that the error reads `d is not defined` but I can't figure out why.